# Dynamic rule based CEP

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I am working on a project where there is a continuous stream of events. There are many concurrent users who can create/update/delete rules and get alerts when the stream matches those rules.

I used Esper for this where I am generating EPL statements from rules dynamically and registering them. This is very error prone as the rules at times are complex and cannot be dynamically converted to EPL. This is also not scalable.

What would be the correct approach to handle this? Is there a standard way/ library for this kind of use cases.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well complex event processing engines are usually used to address complex requirements. As the name says, we are looking for complex relationships between events and time, so its complex event processing.

Simple event processing would be for simple requirements. Simple requirements can be tested with just two scenarios. For example, assume we want to look for an event with a temperature over 100. The design for this in Esper EPL is “select * from Event(temperature > 100). This can be tested by two or maybe three scenarios: Event={temp=99}, Event={temp=100} and Event={temp=101}, for example.

There are some use cases for medium complexity event processing. Those usually require between 4 and 9 scenarios for testing. For example, assume we want to look for more than 100 events arriving within one sliding minute (sliding, not hopping).  The design for this in Esper EPL is “select count(*) from Event#time(60) having count(*) > 100”. This now needs a bunch of scenarios for testing this rule, such as no events, 100 events, 101 events, 101 events over 61 seconds etc. etc.. There is time involved here which makes these scenarios more difficult to describe and test.

I would say that complex event processing is for cases of medium to high complexity of event processing. This is the sort of stuff where you need to be clear about the requirements first. You need to nail down your different scenarios of events arriving and time passing before going to design Esper EPL.

Requirements drive the tool. Esper does handle the more complex requirements well but there is a learning curve. In my experience scaling can be done but needs planning. When talking about low latency analysis and scaling in one sentence there is no silver bullet simple approach. There is high availability for Esper but that is not for free but that scales well in a Kafka stack.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source project called StreamingFlow4J that’s solve it in Esper CEP. It easily makes CRUD operations in Epl rules.